# Is there a way to use an SQL Server Agent to write a .txt report file after multiple steps?

Tags: sql-server, txt, sql-server-agent

Goodmorning fellow programmers,

I'm working on a company's server, trying to implement **daily check functions** on our databases via **SQL server agents**.
These functions are scheduled to run every morning, do their things (mostly check on conflicts between the reports of our production software and the ones in our business management one) and then send an email with the query results to me.
The SQL Server Agent i'm working on proceeds to do its job with multiple steps, and at the end of every step it sends me an email; this is acceptable right now that it only sends me 2 emails daily but it's going to be a mess once i implement 10+ steps so i'm thinking about **a way to compile a single report file** (a .txt would be more than acceptable) **and only send that one once all the steps are completed.**

Is there any way to do so?

Right now i'm sending the emails with this code:

```
*various DECLAREs*

IF ( *condition* )
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @myquery varchar(1000) = 
       ' *query that checks on my data* '

       SET @mysubject = ' *email subject* ' AS varchar(20));
       SET @mybody = ' *email body* ';

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'db_mailer',
         @recipients = @mailTo,
         @copy_recipients = @mailCc,
         @body = @mybody,
         @subject = @mysubject ,   
         @query = @myquery,
         @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
         @query_attachment_filename = '*filename*.txt',
         @body_format = 'HTML' ;
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
       SET @mysubject = ' *email subject* ' AS varchar(20));
       SET @mybody = ' *email body* ';

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'db_mailer',
         @recipients = @mailTo,
         @copy_recipients = @mailCc,
         @body = @mybody,
         @subject = @mysubject ,   
         @body_format = 'HTML' ;
   END
```

The problem is that as long as i know there's no way to let the next step in the Server Agent routine inherit the @myquery string to build a big report in a second moment.
I've already looked for **a way to write a file with SQL** (OLE Automation, bcp.exe, xp_cmdshell etc.) but i don't think any of this way would suit well in a company environment and honestly i don't know if there's a way to **implement a C#/VB script in my query** to do the job.

This is my first question here so i hope it's all clear, every help is really appreciated!

Comment: Log your results from each job into your own logging table and then compile your report from this as a final step.

Comment: @Stu so, considering that right now i'm not really using a logging table but i'm just sending every query via email, are you suggesting to store the result of every step in a new table (a `#TemporaryTable` maybe?) and then collect it as a final step? In case i decide to use a `#TemporaryTable` would it last until the last step of the agent job or should i use a `##TemporaryTable` one?

Comment: Use a permanent table, either in MSDB or preferably in your own utility database, collate your results and you can then report and audit over time.